# Button does not send mysql query?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can send a "show slave status" query without problems, however nothing happens when apply the same logic to a button. Why?

rename con to con2

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            BindData();


    }


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private DataTable dt;

    string credentials = @"server=172.22.6.10;user id=system;persistsecurityinfo=True;port=3343;database=mysql;Password=975315";
    string sqlQuery = @"show slave status";
    string sqlstopstart = @"stop slave;";


    public void BindData()
    {
        //Opens the connection and sends "show slave status" command.
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(credentials);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


        adp.Fill(ds); //Fill Dataset.
        dt = ds.Tables[0]; //Then assign table to dt.


        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) //Checks the server if it is running or not.
        {
            string value = dataRow.Field<string>("Slave_IO_Running");


            if (value == "Yes")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Working";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Not Working";
            }


        }

        //Shows a view of the whole query
        GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection con2 = new MySqlConnection(credentials);
        con2.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstopstart, con2);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you clicked the button1 ?

Comment: Is it in purpose, that you don't do anything with the `adp` object in the button click event?

Comment: Have set a break point and seen that the debugger is able to step into the `Button1_Click1` method after clicking the button?

Comment: Yes the breakpoint gets hit when i click the button.

Comment: There is nothing happening in `Button1_Click1`. Your are only opening the _SqlConnection_. Nothing more. You are missing `adp.Fill(...)` or something similar which causes the query to be executed.

Comment: That was it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the Button1_Click1 event method is missing the adapter fill and actually executing the sql command. You can try doing something similar like you did in BindData() ( maybe actually re-use the method if that is the requirement )